# AppShellMain in Mantine covers the entire screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, mantine

Im creating a log in with next and Mantine
my code:

```
export default function RootLayout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <html lang='es'>
      <Head>
        ...
      </Head>
      <body>
        <AuthUserProvider>
          <MantineProvider theme={theme}>
            <Notifications position="top-left" zIndex={1000} autoClose={9000} limit={5} />
            <AppShell >
              <AppShellMain>{children}</AppShellMain>
              <AppShellFooter pos='unset'>
                <Footer />
              </AppShellFooter>
            </AppShell>
          </MantineProvider>
        </AuthUserProvider>
      </body>
    </html >
  );
}
```

AppShellMain is using all the height of the screen, and to can watch the AppShellFooter i need to sroll down

[main](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dKzs.png)
as you can see the childre doesn't use all the height
[children](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8cRX.png)

I would like to fit the size or something to can see the footer but without use position fixed